# Is it necessary to set autorelease within alloc statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Assume following code,

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"];


[str autorelease];
```

I have seen many times that, Most of the programmers do prefer to put ***alloc***, ***init*** simultaneously within one statement.

Here, I am asking for the possibility of dividing autorelease for next statement.

- For example, It is recommended to put init with alloc statement.
  Is it same for ***autorelease*** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Most of the programmers do prefer to put alloc, init simultaneously within one statement.

That’s because the instance returned by the initialiser is not necessarily the one returned by `+alloc`. For example, this is wrong and will crash your program:

```
NSString *str = [NSString alloc];
[str initWithString:@"sagar"];
```

because in this case `-initWithString:` causes the deallocation of the previous instance, and `str` ends up pointing to a deallocated object. This can be fixed by:

```
NSString *str = [NSString alloc];
str = [str initWithString:@"sagar"];
```

so that `str` points to the different instance returned by `-initWithString:`. The form:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"];
```

guarantees that `str` points to the correct instance.

---

That said, `-autorelease` is different. Unless it’s been overridden by an evil djinn, it always returns the receiver itself. This means that both:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"];
str = [str autorelease];
```

and:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"];
[str autorelease];
```

are correct and work in the same manner.

As for the distinction between:

```
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"] autorelease];
```

and:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"];
…
[str autorelease];
```

some people prefer to use `-autorelease` in tandem with allocation to avoid forgetting to autorelease the instance later. Others prefer to place it in the `return` statement (if any):

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"sagar"];
…
return [str autorelease];
```

to make (more) explicit that the method/function returns an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use autorelease anywhere within the scope, in fact the most common usage is

```
return [object autorelease]
```

When you want to return an object to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this

```
MyObject* foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
...
[foo autorelease];
...
return foo;
```

or this

```
MyObject* foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
...
...
return [foo autorelease];
```

or this

```
MyObject* foo = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
...
...
return foo;
```

I would go with either the second or third, but it's personal preference.

If it's a temporary object that you don't return, you can do this:

```
MyObject* foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
...
[foo autorelease];
...
return somethingElse;
```

or this

```
MyObject* foo = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
...
...
return somethingElse;
```

or this

```
MyObject* foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
...
[foo release];
...
return somethingElse;
```

In this case, I don't think you ever see the first option.  After all, why do autorelease when you can also do release.  You see the second option quite a lot.  It means you don't have to remember to do the release later.  You also see the third option a lot.  It has the advantage on iOS of not holding on to unneeded memory for longer than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can put autorelease in next statement, but the scope of this str will be local and when control is out of scope, this string will be released....

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue if you put *autorelease* in the next statement.

*autorelease* object is automatically put into autorelease pool, when the scope of that object ends. Means, compiler automatically adds *release* message when scope of that object ends and in that case, you don't have to write *release* message for that object. An autorelease pool stores objects that are sent a release message when the pool itself is drained.

The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event. If you use the Application Kit, you therefore typically don’t have to create your own pools. If your application creates a lot of temporary autoreleased objects within the event loop, however, it may be beneficial to create “local” autorelease pools to help to minimize the peak memory footprint.

On main thread, *[myObj autorelease]* will automatically throw myObj into pool, at the end of perticular event loop, managed by system itself. But, to use *[myObj autorelease]* in case of secondary threads, you will have to use NSAutoreleasePool. Otherwise if a pool is not available, autoreleased objects do not get released and you leak memory.

For example, for secondary threads:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.

[pool release];
```

Remember, never release an object after pool itself has been released. This will either cause a crash or any unexpected output. I mentioned this because, **I have paid a big cost of making this mistake.**

If your project is developed under ARC, you don't have to worry anymore about retain, release, autorelease. Apple recommends to use ARC environment.